Export all Voice Memos on macOS Sequoia
I'm trying to export all Voice Memos from my Mac (running macOS Sequoia 15.0), including timestamps and names (as shown in Voice Memos). If Voice Memos stores location co-ordinates inside its database, getting that would be nice as well.
I can drag-and-drop Voice Memos one at a time into Finder to export them. I can also use cmd+c & cmd+v to copy them into Finder. I have hundreds of Voice Memos (over several years), so saving them one at a time is not feasible (or, at least, very tedious and likely unreliable). Cmd+a or shift-select to select multiple recordings at a time does not work.
I've looked at this to automate the process:
https://github.com/robbyHuelsi/macOSVoiceMemosExporter/blob/master/main.py
But, for the path it uses:
os.path.expanduser("~"), "Library", "Application Support", "com.apple.voicememos", "Recordings", "CloudRecordings.db"

Which doesn't exist on my computer (apparently the location and/or the way Voice Memos stores them got changed).
So, is there a better way to reliably and automatically export all Voice Memos, including metadata (at least timestamp and name) to a folder, than (1) copy-pasting every recording manually, or (2) writing a script that uses keyboard shortcuts to automate copy-pasting each Voice Memo one at a time?

I found .m4a format recordings and other Voice Memos support files at this path in Sequoia 15.1:
/Users/icondaemon/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.VoiceMemos.shared/Recordings/
I've never used Voice Memos, so my results are 'fresh from the oven', so to speak, without any cruft from previous versions or recordings. I hope this helps.
I found the path above by running Activity Monitor, finding and selecting the Voice Memos process, then selecting Open Files and Ports. If you look at the bottom few lines, you can usually find user-related files & paths.
